# pytest: how to NOT run all test combinations of a parametrized class method?

Tags: python, pytest

I have a test class with a parametrization in all methods. I also want to parametrize some methods with other variables. However, I do not want to run all combination (as some of them will always fail).

Consider the following:

```py
@pytest.mark.parametrize("base_url", ["api/v1/actions/", "api/v1/quotes/"])
class TestAPIResponse:

    @pytest.mark.parametrize("api_verbose_name", ["ação", "declaração"])
    def test_example(self, api_client, base_url, api_verbose_name):
        ...
```

With this configuration we have 4 tests:

1. `base_url = "api/v1/actions/"` and `api_verbose_name = "ação"`
2. `base_url = "api/v1/quotes/"` and `api_verbose_name = "declaração"`
3. `base_url = "api/v1/actions/"` and `api_verbose_name = "declaração"`
4. `base_url = "api/v1/quotes/"` and `api_verbose_name = "ação"`

How can I make `test_example` run only the 3rd and 4th test described above?

Right now I'm doing getting the `api_verbose_name` through a helper function...

```py
def get_api_verbose_name(base_url: str) -> str:
    if "quotes" in base_url:
        api_verbose_name = "declaração"
    if "actions" in base_url:
        api_verbose_name = "ação"

    return api_verbose_name


@pytest.mark.parametrize("base_url", ["api/v1/actions/", "api/v1/quotes/"])
class TestAPIResponse:
    
    def test_example(self, api_client, base_url):
        api_verbose_name = get_api_verbose_name(base_url=base_url)
        ...
```

... but this does not seem to be the ideal way for me.

Can I execute this set of tests without this helper function?

Comment: sounds like you're trying to make parametrize do too much -- if you didn't parametrize the whole class you could select your combinations explicitly -- beyond that you'll probably need to do something what you're doing where you map the endpoint to the specific name to use (or do the whole parametrization and `pytest.skip()` / `pytest.xfail()` the invalid combinations) - a pytest core dev

Comment: Sorry @AnthonySottile I didn't understand what you are suggesting. Could you provide a minimal example, please?

Answer (score 0):

Going slightly off what @AnthonySottile said, if you know the endpoint you want to skip you can mark it in your call to `pytest.mark.parametrize`. The example below shows how to do that by taking advantage of [`pytest.param`](https://docs.pytest.org/en/stable/reference.html#pytest-param).

```
import pytest


def example(base, api):
    return f"{base}{api}"


@pytest.mark.parametrize("base_url", ["api/v1/actions/", "api/v1/quotes/"])
class TestAPI:
    @pytest.mark.parametrize("api_verbose_name", 
        ["ação", pytest.param("declaração", marks=pytest.mark.skip)]
    )
    def test_example(self, base_url, api_verbose_name):
        result = example(base_url, api_verbose_name)
        assert result == f"{base_url}{api_verbose_name}"
```

And when we run the tests we can see that four tests are collected by only two are ran since the rest are skipped.

```
collected 4 items                                                                                                                                               

test_foo.py ..ss                                                                                                                                          [100%]

================================================================= 2 passed, 2 skipped in 0.02s ==================================================================
```

Comment: doing like this we are skipping the `declaração` `api_verbose_name` for both endpoints, aren't we?

Comment: yes, based on your question that is desired behavior, you said how to run just test 1 and test 4 which both skip that api verbose name

Comment: I made a mistake and just edit the question. It was the 3rd and 4th, actually.

Comment: if you just need those two then just make those two separate tests where you specify which verbose name to skip, so you would have one test for each endpoint and then for each of those specific tests you should skip the verbose name you want.